# How to make my angular application lightweight

Tags: angular

I am using angular 7 in my application.

When I have started the application using localhost:4200 in developers tools network tab too many CSS, scss, js...... are loading.
But I don't need to load all of them. I need only the login module and corresponding styles...
So that my application will work very fast.

How to do this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You are build in dev mode, the size of the produced files do not matter in development mode. Once you build using AoT in production then you should have much smaller files because of Tree Shaking and minification (among other things). See also https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: Check if you are lazy loading your modules https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules]

Comment: Analyze the bundle size by using: `webpack-bundle-analyzer`. https://coryrylan.com/blog/analyzing-bundle-size-with-the-angular-cli-and-webpack

Comment: https://itnext.io/how-to-optimize-angular-applications-99bfab0f0b7c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to increase the overall performance of your angular application. In your specific case you can simply `ng serve --aot=true --prod` and that should speed up the performance of your development client but, will make the hot refresh feature extremely slow. Would not recommend for development.

However, since I spend a ton of time on this I thought I might list my favorite ways to improve performance:

## #1. LAZY LOADING MODULES

(in my experience) Most people pick Angular for large projects due to it's opinionated and organized design. However, performance for large projects tends to suffer especially if everything is in one place like an Angular app. However, because of Angular's modular design we can decide when chunks of our app will load.

For the most clear instructions on how to implement this in your app i suggest reading the docs https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules but, I will give a short example here:

1. Add routing to your project (on a new project just use `ng new App` and add routing from the cli)
2. Create a sub module with routing `ng generate module mySubModule --routing`
3. Update the routing module in your `app-routing.module.ts` file to look somewhat like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: '',
   loadComponent: HomeComponent
 },
 {
   path: 'mysubroute',
   loadChildren: () => import('./mySubModule/mySubModule.module').then(mod => mod.MySubModuleModule)
 },
]
```

then everything in your sub module wont load unless you're on /mysubroute or after everything else has loaded. Easy right?

## #2. Server Side Rendering

<strike>*NOTE* The new way to lazy load feature modules does *not* work with Angular Universal. You need to use the old string method. You can find an example for that [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-6-lazy-loading-example/)</strike> (no longer necessary for newer versions of angular)

Server side rendering can improve web performance significantly especially if your page does not change very much. But, this is a much more advanced topic and requires some understanding of how servers, server-cacheing works especially if you decide not to use express.

It is fairly easy to add angular universal to your project though `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject angular.io-example`

## #3. Don't use a 'shared module' when using feature modules.

A lot of tutorials suggest using a shared-module when developing because it does make your life a lot easier. You have to worry a lot less about missing imports and confusing bugs in your templates.

However, that does come with some cost. If you import every single component into every single one of your modules then you will be loading those components up-front every time.

Generally speaking, for the best performance you only want to load what you need at any given time. I find the best way to do this is to make a module for each component and import them when necessary. This may slow runtime performance a small bit, it speeds up initial load times.

## #4. Oldschool web performance tricks still work.

- Lazy loading your images
- Optimizing huge images
- Limiting the amount of additional fonts
- Adding compression to your server
- Deferring unused css

Angular does a lot for us but, huge resources are really the source of bad load times. Loading a 3.4mb background image does no one any favors except my mobile data company.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you to use Lazy loading. Check [Alligator](https://alligator.io/angular/lazy-loading/)

> With lazy loaded modules in Angular, it’s easy to have features loaded
>   only when the user navigates to their routes for the first time. This
>   can be a huge help for your app’s performance and reducing the initial
>   bundle size. Plus, it’s pretty straightforward to setup!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach: once you have imported all your modules with deferred load. You can create a custom structural directive, to render your components if you are in viewPort. It is a merger between the * ngIf directive and the interceptor observer. But if the component has already been rendered, we do nothing. Imagine that you have a dashboard module with several component cards, images, carousel, and when we are scrolling, that begins to render, this behavior greatly improves the initial load of a home page